# How do you get PHP5 scripts to work under gentoo linux?

Tags: php, lamp, vps

I ran
"emerge apache"
"emerge php"
"emerge mysql"

I set apache + mysql to run at launch

I set the use flags for PHP, CGI, APACHE, MYSQL

I went into httpd.conf and added "-D PHP"

PHP scripts will not run.  The contents of the script are just sent back to the web browser.

That is the result of retrieving "test.php" from a web-browser

I am baffled and frustrated.  I have spend at least 6 hours trying to this LAMP setup working on this VPS.  Please help me!

Also, "emerge mod_php" does not work.  It tells me that no such package exists

Comment: this question is better suited to serverfault.com

you should also use $ emerge search apache | less 


then type /php 

to find the package to install for mod php

Comment: I fixed the problem.  I installed CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you add "-D PHP"?

You should edit `/etc/conf.d/apache2` and append `"-D PHP5"` to the `APACHE2_OPTS`.

Comment: I fixed the problem.  I installed CentOS :P